RowCallBack function for Jquery datatable coloring text and background with ajax returned value from mysql
Need some light on this issue in the attached screenshot. If I entered fixed color value (ie #ffffff for both font and row background) it worked nicely.
However, I want to use the value returned from ajax call as pointed with arrow, if I used val() function, not working. Also didn't give me any error message.
Thanks for your help.
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#empTable').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            'ajax': {
                'url':'diary2024-ajaxfile.php'
            },
            'columns': [
                { data: 'stamp1' },
        { data: 'enteron' },
        { data: 'story1' },
                { data: 'story2' },
                { data: 'menu_name' },
        { data: 'fcolor' },
        { data: 'bcolor' },
        { data: 'fileupload' },
        { data: 'viewfile' },
        { data: 'testing' },
                { data: 'menu_id' },
        { data: 'zcheckbox' },

            ],
'columnDefs': [
       { orderable:false, targets: 6 }
            ],
            
'aaSorting': [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                             
                             
 fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                        
if (aData.menu_name == "HBL") {
                            $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'val(data.bcolor)');
            $('td', nRow).css('color', 'val(data.fcolor)');
                        }
    if (aData.menu_name == "Garden") {
            $('td', nRow).css('color', '#0542fa');
        $('td', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                        }
if (aData.menu_name == "HOME") {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', '#0d05fc');
        $('td', nRow).css('color', '#ffffff');
                        }


As per the .css syntax you need to directly give the color value.
Also data.bcolor should be aData.bcolor
Modified working code:
if (aData.menu_name == "HBL") {
    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', aData.bcolor);
    $('td', nRow).css('color', aData.fcolor);
}

Note: make sure that aData has bcolor and fcolor properties along with correct values.
Sample hardcoded example:


$(function() {
  //to show you that if your aData variable will have proper bcolor and folor attribute, it will work
  let aData1 = {
    'bcolor': '#808080',
    'fcolor': '#ff0000'
  };
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
      $('td', nRow).css('background-color', aData1.bcolor);
      $('td', nRow).css('color', aData1.fcolor);
    }
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$4,525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$4,525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Russell Chavez</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shad Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Thanks for your response. I tried with aData.fcolor. The datatable disappeared completely. All the row suddenly gone.

if (aData.menu_name == "HBL") {
$('td', nRow).css('background-color', aData.bcolor);
$('td', nRow).css('color', aData.fcolor)');
}

@Danny I have edited my solution. I have added an hardcoded example for your understanding. Have a look. I hope it will help you to correct your code.

@Danny  did you checked my edited solution?

@Danny  "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's How does accepting an answer work?. Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"
